# Please explain why 2x * /2 became 2/2x

Tags: quadratics, radicals, factoring

I'm studying a Grade 10 maths book and was surprised to see the correct answer for this question was:

(/2 - 3x)(/3 + 2x) - /5x

= /6 + 2/2x - 3/3x - 6x - /5x

I thought it should be:

= /6 + 2x/2 - 3x/3 - 6x - /5x

I'm using this '/' symbol for the radical sign

Can you please help me understand why the variable x is placed inside the radical sign?

Thank you.

Comment: What you don't understand is that $2x\sqrt2=2\sqrt2 x$?

Comment: correct. Not sure why that happens

Comment: $2x\sqrt{2} = 2\cdot x \cdot \sqrt{2}$.  Now... remember that $a\cdot b\cdot c = a\cdot c\cdot b$ by the commutative property of multiplication... so $2\cdot x\cdot \sqrt{2} = 2\cdot \sqrt{2}\cdot x$

Comment: is it equally correct to say 2x/2 in that case?

Comment: By /5x, do you mean $\sqrt{5x}$ or $\sqrt 5\cdot x$?

Comment: Yes, though it is uncommon to.  It is far more common to write the simplified (*as best as possible*) coefficient in front of the $x$ when possible.

Comment: ahhhh of course. In the answers the radical sign doesn't go over the x, just the two. Little confusing. Thanks for your help. Feeling a bit silly

Comment: As for typing math here, visit [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on typing with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on this site so that it is not so confusing reading what you have written.  `$\sqrt{6} + 2x\cdot \sqrt{2} - 3x\cdot \sqrt{3}$` produces $\sqrt{6} + 2x\cdot \sqrt{2} - 3x\cdot \sqrt{3}$ for example.  That being said, although there are infinitely many "correct" ways you could write it, there are certainly some ways that are considered better or more proper than others.

Comment: I appreciate that! I was wondering how you were writing the symbols correctly. I'll check that out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing comments above., by the commutative property of multiplication (*which says that $a\times b = b\times a$ for any reals $a,b$*) you have that:

$2\times x \times \sqrt{2} = 2\times \sqrt{2} \times x$

or, written with fewer multiplication signs but meaning the same thing:

$2x\times \sqrt{2} = 2\sqrt{2} ~x$

"*can you help me understand why $x$ is placed inside the radical sign?*"

$x$ does not go inside of the radical sign.  Note the difference in meaning of $\sqrt{2x}=\sqrt{(2x)}$ and $\sqrt{2}~x=(\sqrt{2})~x$.  The length of the horizontal bar of the radical denotes which terms following are included inside of the radical versus outside of the radical.